# printの出力結果が改行されるのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: ruby

### ソース

```
print "aaaaaaa\
bbbbbb"
```

### 結果

```
aaaaaaabbbbbb
```

これは納得がいくのですが、

### ソース

```
print "aaaaaaa\n
bbbbbb"
```

### 結果

```
aaaaaaa

bbbbbb
```

は何故でしょうか？

```
aaaaaaa
         #<= ここの行はなぜ出現？？
bbbbbb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[リテラル (Ruby 2.3.0)](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/doc/spec=2fliteral.html#string)には

> 複数行にわたって書くこともできます。 この場合含まれる改行文字は常に\nになります。

とあるので
文字列中の改行 --> `\n` --> `print`時に改行
となり後者のような結果になります。また

> ダブルクォートで囲まれた文字列ではバックスラッシュ記法と式展開(後述)が有効になります。

及びバックスラッシュ記法として

> \改行
>
> 文字列中に改行を含めずに改行

とあることから、前者の挙動を説明できます。

Answer (score 2):

文字列の中で改行がされているからです。

### 例1

```
print "aaaaaaa\
bbbbbb"
```

この例では、文字列の中で改行されていますが、`\`を使って行を継続させているので、

```
aaaaaaabbbbbb
```

このように、改行されずに出力されます。

### 例2

```
print "aaaaaaa\n
bbbbbb"
```

この例では、改行を表す`\n`と文字列の中の改行がありますので、2回改行されます。

```
aaaaaaa

bbbbbb
```

### 例3

```
print "aaaaaaa\n\
bbbbbb"
```

この例では、`\n`で一度改行されていますが、文字列中の改行は`\`で継続させていますので、以下のように出力されます

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbb
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` は改行コード (0x0a) を表すバックスラッシュ記法です。
ご質問の例だと `\n` の後ろに 改行コード (0x0a) が含まれています。
結果、改行コードが2つ出力されるので 空の行が表示されます。

出力をダンプするとよく分かります。

```
$ ruby -e 'print "aaaaaaa
bbbbbb"' | od -c
0000000   a   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   b   b   b   b   b   b  ←改行が1つ出現
0000016
$ ruby -e 'print "aaaaaaa\n
bbbbbb"' | od -c
0000000   a   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n  \n   b   b   b   b   b   b  ←改行が2つ出現
0000017
```